# script to be able to edit a shapefile to the same borders of another shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to have a script to be able to edit a shapefile to the same borders of another shapefile that I have. I have city boundary polyline and I want to move the vertices to the same vertex location of another shapefile called parcel.

Is there any script that do the whole process authomatically?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built into ArcGIS with the "Snap" tool.  You do not need to write a script to do this.

In ArcGIS Pro:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm

In ArcGIS Desktop: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm#

Basically you tell the tool which layer you want to snap, and which layer you want to snap to and then define the method.  In your case it sounds like you would want the "vertex" method.  You can then set the tolerance in whichever unit you want, but you have to type it manually.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, the "Snap" tool does not create output data.  It alters the original data.  So...  export a copy first unless you're sure you've setup the tool the way you intend.

Answer (score -1):

Some of these editing tasks are better if they are supervised on a case-by-case basis by the editor.  I believe this task would require editing using map topology.  Once you have completed the vertex moves, build geodatabase topology and check for gaps and overlaps.